# All closed rational rays measurable implies $f$ measurable

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, measure-theory, proof-verification

Is the following proof correct?

Let $f: X \to \mathbb{R}$ where $X$ is a measurable space. Suppose $\{x: f(x) \geq r\}$ is measurable for each $r \in \mathbb{Q}$. Then, $f$ is measurable.

Proof:

Let $U \subset \mathbb{R}$ so that $U = (a,b)$. Then, there exists sequences $\{r_n(a) : r_n \in \mathbb{Q}\}_{n \in \mathbb{N}} \to a$ and 
$\{r_n(b) : r_n \in \mathbb{Q}\}_{n \in \mathbb{N}} \to b$. Thus, we may write $$(a,b) = \bigcup_{n \in \mathbb{N}} [r_n(a), \infty) \cap \bigcup_{n \in \mathbb{N}} [r_n(b), \infty).$$
Therefore, $$f^{-1}(U) = \bigcup_{n \in \mathbb{N}} f^{-1}([r_n(a), \infty)) \cap \bigcup_{n \in \mathbb{N}} f^{-1}([r_n(b), \infty))$$
with the lhs being measurable by the properties of a measurable space.

Any issues with this proof?

Comment: You should take $a<r_n(a)<r_n(b)<b$ in order to ensure that your first displayed equation holds true. Otherwise the proof seems to be correct.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The identity

$$(a,b) = \bigcup_{n \in \mathbb{N}} [r_n(a),\infty) \cap \bigcup_{n \in \mathbb{N}} [r_n(b),\infty)$$ is not correct. As @uniquesolution pointed out in his (her) comment, you need to assume that $a<r_n(a)<r_n(b)<b$, but even then the identity does not hold true. Instead, it should read

$$(a,b) = \bigcup_{n \in \mathbb{N}} [r_n(a),\infty) \cap \bigcup_{n \in \mathbb{N}} (-\infty,r_n(b)).$$

Comment: ..@saz i have some confusion in $$(a,b) = \bigcup_{n \in \mathbb{N}} [r_n(a),\infty) \cap \bigcup_{n \in \mathbb{N}} (-\infty,r_n(b)).$$
why u didn't put $(-\infty,r_n(b)]$ instead of $(-\infty,r_n(b))?$

Comment: @jasmine Doesn't really make a difference.

Comment: okss thanks u @Saz