# Weaker condition for determine if a function is measurable.

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

I want to prove the following statement:

If $f$ is a real function over a measure space $X$ such {$x$/ $f(x)$ $\ge$ $r$} is measurable for each rational , then $f$ is measurable.

So far , this is what I have:

Picking up a rational number sequence {$q_{1}$$>$$q_{2}$...$>$$q_{n}$$>$$r$} then lim {$q_{n}$}=$r$ as te sequence {$q_{n}$} is decreasing when $n$ is incresing and is also lower bounded by $r$ then this implies that ($r$ ,$\infty$)=$\bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty}$ [$q_{n}$ ,$\infty$) and I know that a sigma algebra is closed over countable unions

How can I end up this proof and properly argue it in case my thought so far is OK.??

Thanks

Comment: Let $r_1>r_2>\cdots r_n>\cdots $ be a sequence of rationals converging from above to $a\in \mathbb R$, Then the sets $A_m=\left \{ x:f(x)\geq r_{m} \right \}$ are measureable, Now take the intersection over $m$

Comment: Got it ! Since the instersection of the sets $A_{m]$ is measurable as the measurable sets are sigma-algebra  but the intersection of  the sets $A_{m]$ is ${ x:f(x)>= a}$ and this is an equivalence for $f$ is a measurable function. Thanks dude

Comment: See also this question: http://math.stackexchange.com/q/1418853/