# what is the used of $\{x:f(x) \ge r\}$ in the given answer?

Tags: measure-theory

Prove that if $f$ is a real function on a measurable space $X$ such that $\{x:f(x) \ge r\}$ is measurable for every rational $r$, then $f$ is measurable.

My attempt : I got the answer [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1418853/all-closed-rational-rays-measurable-implies-f-measurable)

I have some confusion in the given answer below

[image]

**My confusion** : what is the  used of $\{x:f(x) \ge r\}$ in the given answer ?

**My thinking**: There is no relation between the $\{x:f(x) \ge r\}$ and the given above answer .Then how can i claim that this  answer is correct .

I think given answer  is not match with given question

Comment: $\{x: f(x)\ge r\}=f^{-1}([r,\infty ])$ (assuming here that $f$ is $\overline{\mathbb{R}}$ valued)

Comment: oks @Masacroso But $\{x:f(x) \le r\}=$
$f^{-1}(-\infty ,r]) $ is not  given. in the question .Question is asking about only $\{x:f(x) \ge r\}$

Comment: note that $f^{-1}((-\infty ,r])=(f^{-1}((r,\infty )))^\complement $, so it is enough to show that if $f^{-1}([r,\infty ))$ is measurable for all $r$ then $f^{-1}((r,\infty ))$ is also measurable for all $r$

Comment: @Masacroso     u mean $f^{-1}(-\infty,r])$ is also measurable for all $r$ in ur last sentence ?

Comment: if $f^{-1}(A)$ is measurable then it is also $f^{-1}(A^\complement )=(f^{-1}(A))^\complement $